# Javascript click function not working for automatic open

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on some code that include tabs using HTML, CSS, and Javascript by using button classes. I want one specific tab (button) to open automatically when the user clicks on the site. In other words, I want the tab to be opened by default without the user having to click on anything.

```js
function openPage(pageName, elmnt, color) {
          // Hide all elements with class="tabcontent" by default */
          var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
          tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
          for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
          }
        
          // Remove the background color of all tablinks/buttons
          tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
          for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
          }
        
          // Show the specific tab content
          document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
        
          // Add the specific color to the button used to open the tab content
          elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;
        }
        
        // Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
        document.getElementById("index").click();
```

```css
    .tablink {
      float: left;
    
      margin-top: 28px;
      margin-left: 100px;
      padding: 5px font-size: 12px;
    
      cursor: pointer;
    
      color: black;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      background-color: transparent;
    
      font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
      font-size: 15px;
    }
    
    .tablink:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
    
      background-color: white;
    }
    
    /* Style the tab content (and add height:100% for full page content) */
    .tabcontent {
        display: none;
    
        height: 100%;
        padding: 20px 20px;
    
        color: black;
    }
```

```html
 <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('index', this, 'white')" id="indextab">INDEX</button>
  <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('faq', this, 'white')">FAQ</button>
  <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('other', this, 'white')">OTHER</button>
  <div id="faq" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>News</h3>
    <p>Some news this fine day!</p>
  </div>

  <div id="other" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Contact</h3>
    <p>Get in touch, or swing by for a cup of coffee.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="index" class="tabcontent">
  <p>
  I should run first!
  </p>
  </div>
```

This is the specific code for the problem, but if you want to see the actual work without seeing the code, here's where it's located (https://cheyennecodespreview.tumblr.com/). The index tab should be the one opening by default.

Comment: I believe you should be trying to click the element with `id=indextab` not `id=index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you have mentioned here, if you want to open Index Tab on page load you can use below code.

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  // - Code to execute when all DOM content is loaded.
  document.getElementById('indextab').click();
 });
```